# What Does Assembly Instruction Shift Do?

Tags: shellcode

I came across a pretty interesting 
[article](http://turkeyland.net/projects/overflow/shell.php) that demonstrated how to remove nullbyte characters from shellcode.  Among the techniques used, the assembly instructions `shl` and `shr` seemed to occupy a rather important role in the code.

I realize that the assembly instructions `mov $0x3b, %rax` and `mov $59, %rax` each actually generate the machine code instructions `48 c7 c0 3b 00 00 00`.  So to cope for this, the author instead uses `mov $0x1111113b, %rax` to fill the register with the system call number, which generates instead the machine code `48 c7 c0 3b 11 11 11`, which successfully removes nullbytes.

Unfortunately, the code still doesn't execute because syscall treats `3b 11 11 11` as an illegal instruction, or this causes the code to seg fault.  So what the author then did was shift `%rax` back and forth 56 bytes with the commands

```
shl $0x38, %rax 
shr $0x38, %rax
```

After this shift, the code executes perfectly.  What I want to know is how the shift instructions fixes the `48 c7 c0 3b 11 11 11` issue, and somehow makes `%rax` proper and syscall'able.  I know that the `shl/shr` shifts bits left and right, meaning that shifting left moves the bits up into higher bits, and shifting right makes them lower again, because binary is read right to left.  But how does this at all change the code and make it executable?  Doesn't shifting back and forth essentially change nothing, putting the shifted bits exactly back where they were in the beginning?

My only theory is that shifting bits away leaves behind zeros.  But I still don't see how shifting `%rax` forward and then back fixes the solution, because wouldn't it bring back the `11 11 11` section anyway?

Anyways, I thought this was interesting as I had never seen the shift operands before today.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting is a lossy operation - if bits are shifted outside of the register, they just disappear. (Sometimes one of them is stored in a carry flag, but that's not important here.) See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate#Logical_Shift_Instructions .

The shift left (shl) operation does this:

0x000000001111113b << 0x38 = 0x3b00000000000000

The 0x111111 part would have occupied bit 64, 65, 66 etc., but %rax is a 64-bit register, so those bits vanish. Then, the logical shift right (shr) operation does this:

0x3b00000000000000 >> 0x38 = 0x000000000000003b

Giving you the number that you want. And that's all there is to it.